# Xslt under some conditions

Tags: xml, regex, xslt

I am new to xml and xslt. I have some data which is in the form of some values.

Suppose This is an xml

```
<root>
    <z>517-98-0045</z>
    <z1>449-235-1235</z1>
    <z2>4265-6857-1293-0098</z2>
    <z3>3232-3-3232-3232-12</z3>
    <z4>449-235-1235</z4>
    <z5>332323-32-322</z5>
    <z6>218-28-2332</z6>
    <z7>517-98-0045</z7>
</root>
```

It should be changed to the following:

```
<z>517-xx-xxxx</z>
<z1>449-xxx-xxxx</z1>
<z2>4265-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx</z2>
<z3>3232-3-3232-3232-12</z3>
<z4>449-xxx-xxxx</z4>
<z5>332323-32-322</z5>
<z6>218-28-2332</z6>
<z7>517-xx-xxxx</z7>
```

So this means whenever xslt comes accross the three values

```
517-98-0045
449-235-1235
4265-6857-1293-0098
```

it has to transform it into this

```
517-XX-XXXX
449-XXX-XXXX
4265-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
```

I know that regular expressions can accomplish this, but how can I do that?

According to the undergiven answers..Is this following correct---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:when test="matches(517-98-0045,'\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}')">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace('517-98-0045','517-XX-XXXX');"/>
  </xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="matches(449-235-1235,'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}')">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace('449-235-1235','449-XX-XXXX');"/>
  </xsl:when>
<xsl:when test="matches(4265-6857-1293-0098,'\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}')">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace('4265-6857-1293-0098','4265-XXxx-XXXX-xxxx');"/>
  </xsl:when>
<xsl:template>
<xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Do you mean just those three literal values?

Comment: Yes @michael.hor257K only these three literal value when it comes (specificaly)

Comment: I don't think you need regex for that.

Comment: The stylesheet you have now added is marked version 1.0. You cannot use replace() or regex in XSLT 1.0. Why don't you post an example of the input XML and the required output. Understanding what this is about would also help. It seems a rather strange request.

Comment: Should the digits be replaced with `X` (capital) or `x` (lowercase)? Your question seems to use a random mixture of both.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to replace those three particular values, then this should do it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()[. = '517-98-0045' or
                              . = '449-235-1235' or
                              . = '4265-6857-1293-0098']">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(., '-'), 
                                 '-',
                                 translate(substring-after(., '-'),
                                           '0123456789', 'XXXXXXXXXX'))"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Uhm, you need to have `'XXXXXXXXXX'` as the third argument of translate().

Comment: Indeed I do. My mistake.

Comment: Well, +1 for reading the question (before it changed again...).

Answer (score 0):

following 3 regexes should do the trick:

```
replace('517-98-0045','(\d{3})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})','$1-XX-XXXX');
replace('449-235-1235','(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})','$1-XXX-XXXX');
replace('4265-6857-1293-0098','(\d{4})-(\d{4})-(\d{4})-(\d{4})','$1-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX');
```

the only thing needed now is to check which replace function apply. the function matches could do that:

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="matches(.,'\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}')">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'(\d{3})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})','$1-XX-XXXX');"/>
  </xsl:when>
  ...
```

Comment: Surely replacing a literal value could be done *literally*? E.g. `replace('517-98-0045','517-XX-XXXX')`?

Comment: I've just placed the literal examples because it speaks more for itself. Ofcourse someone could use a variable, node-element or attribute instead of the literal value.

Answer (score 0):

If it is always the first group of digits that should *not* be replaced with `'X'`, the solution below works.

I don't think you need regexes that are more complex than that.

**Sample Input XML** (since you did not show any XML input)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <n>517-98-0045</n>
  <n>449-235-1235</n>
  <n>4265-6857-1293-0098</n> 
</root>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="n">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(.,'-'),'-',replace(substring-after(.,'-'),'\d','X'))"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <n>517-XX-XXXX</n>
  <n>449-XXX-XXXX</n>
  <n>4265-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX</n> 
</root>
```

---

**EDIT** (you updated your question with actual XML input)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/root|root/*">
  <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()[.='4265-6857-1293-0098' or .='449-235-1235' or .='517-98-0045']">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(.,'-'),'-',replace(substring-after(.,'-'),'\d','X'))"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```