# using regex for string replacement in XSLT

Tags: xml, regex, xslt

I am using datapower xi50 and following is my input xml

```
<Sample>
<AccountNumber>37289882</AccountNumber>
<SortCode>789-88-8907</SortCode>
<CardNumber>4545-6767-9876-8764</CardNumber>
<address>j-89-8999</address>
</Sample>
```

I have to get the following output

```
<Sample>
    <AccountNumber>37289882</AccountNumber>
    <SortCode>789-xx-xxxx</SortCode>
    <CardNumber>4545-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx</CardNumber>
    <address>j-89-8999</address>
    </Sample>
```

in particular whenever we have the following format--

```
678-87-2827(3 number-2 number-4 number)
 5253-2626-9808-8787(4 number-4 number-4 number-4 number)
```

we have to change it to

```
678-xx-xxxx
  5253-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
```

Following is what I am doing

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/extensions"
xmlns:dpconfig="http://www.datapower.com/param/config"
xmlns:regexp="http://exslt.org/regular-expressions"
extension-element-prefixes="dp" 
exclude-result-prefixes="dp">
<xsl:template match="/"> 
<xsl:value-of select="regexp:replace(string(.), '-\d{2}-\d{4}', 'i', '-xx-xxxx')"/>
<xsl:value-of select="regexp:replace(string(.), '-\d{4}-\d{4}-\d{4}', 'i', '-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx')"/>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting output now

but the output is comming twice

```
37289882
789-xx-xxxx
4545-6767-9876-8764
j-89-8999

37289882
789-88-8907
4545-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
j-89-8999
```

is it because of twice `<xsl:value-of select>`

Thanks

Comment: A very similar question has been asked yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447830/xslt-under-some-conditions/22450211#22450211.

Comment: True, and [a very simple XSLT 1.0 answer that doesn't require regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22451680/3016153) was posted there too.

Answer (score 2):

The solution below uses XSLT 2.0. I am aware that your stylesheet is in XSLT 1.0 but I do not have access to the EXSLT extension functions right now.

I hope that the [`regexp:match`](http://www.exslt.org/regexp/functions/match/index.html) and [`regexp:replace`](http://www.exslt.org/regexp/functions/replace/index.html) functions are not too different from XSLT 2.0 functionality, so that you can easily adapt the stylesheet yourself.

**Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Sample|Sample/*"> 
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="matches(.,'(\d{3})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})') or matches(.,'(\d{4})-(\d{4})-(\d{4})-(\d{4})')">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(.,'-'),'-',replace(substring-after(.,'-'),'\d','x'))"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Sample>
   <AccountNumber>37289882</AccountNumber>
   <SortCode>789-xx-xxxx</SortCode>
   <CardNumber>4545-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx</CardNumber>
   <address>j-89-8999</address>
</Sample>
```